# Can`t get solutions from swi-prolog and JPL

Tags: java, swi-prolog, jpl

I want to get prolog Solutions by JPL using DCG grammar which one is stored in external file but when I call a method `getSolution` from my class a get an exception from prolog:

```
org.jpl7.PrologException: PrologException: error(existence_error(procedure, 
'/'(zdanie, 3)), context(':'(system, '/'('$c_call_prolog', 0)), _1))
```

**Prolog class :**

```
package kck.project.Parser;

import org.jpl7.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;



public class Prolog {



   public Prolog() {

       if (JPL.init()) {
           Query q1 = new Query("consult('//files/students/s407201/my   documents/kck-cp1250.pl').");
           System.out.print(q1.hasSolution());


    }

}

   public String getSolution(String sentence) {
       String sentenceToParse = sentence.replace(' ', ',');
       Map<String, Term> solution = null;
       Query q4 = new Query("zdanie(X,[" + sentenceToParse + "],[]).");
       while (q4.hasMoreSolutions()) {
           solution = q4.nextSolution();
       }
       return solution.get("X").toString();

   }

}
```